# When we add images in drawable we add all like mdpi, hdpi to image support in all device, but when image comes on server then how can we handle?

Tags: android

When we add images in drawable we add all like mdpi, hdpi xdpi to image support in all device, but when image comes on server then how can we handle, so our image is support in all the device ?

Answer (score 0):

First off you want larger images, not smaller, cant scale up as easily as down. From there is easy, you can use the scaled bitmap function , there are lots of option. However if you are scaling up, good luck, the images will be blurry

Answer (score 0):

If the images are just icons or some small images which are required for apps layout designs, then store those images on client side in mdpi, hdpi, xdpi folders.

If the images are dynamic, put the max size image in server. whenever client apps request for the images ask for the client size(screen size) resize the image using java in your server then send the new images to the client. it is time consuming process.

If you do not want to resize the images at the time of serving request, you can pre process then images and create all the size(mdpi, hdpi, xdpi) images and put in the respective folders in server. whenever client ask for the image, ask the size(screen  size) and get the image from the respective folders and server the response.This process require more space.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it solves your problem, it will help others to solve the problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon various factors,

1. If you are using any external lib
2. images received from server, of  larger resolution then scaling is
   better handled by Android.

Apart drawables added on different resolution are application specific.